# Using Jaca JsonPath to exclude items from JSON response

Tags: java, jsonpath

I am using the JsonSmartJsonProvider and my JSON looks like this

```
  {
  "info": {
    "clientCount": 1,
    "compactorVersion": 2,
    "processMonitor": {
      "processList": [
        {
          "name": "java.exe",
          "commandLine": "",
          "pid": 6224
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to exclude "processList", but keep everything else.  I've tried variations on `$.info[?(@ noneof ['processMonitor'])]`, but I always end up with "info" being empty in the response.  Is it possible to use JsonPath to do this?  The code that is used to do this looks like this:

```
        DocumentContext document = JsonPath.using(CONFIGURATION).parse(json);
        
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        paths.forEach((key, value) -> result.put(key, document.read(value)));
        return result;
```

Comment: jsonpath is used to **query** (or parse) a json payload, and not really to **alter** (or transform) it.

Comment: A coworker added a system that uses the initial JSON along with a JsonPath to create a subset of the initial JSON so that we arent returning as large of a JSON object as would be returned by default.  One call needs the whole thing, another needs one portion of it, another needs another portion, etc so instead of returning the monolithic whole every time we are trying to only return what is needed by the specific requestor.  The code being used:

  DocumentContext document = JsonPath.using(CONFIGURATION).parse(json);

Comment: Ok. Then something like this may be ? `DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(json);
doc.delete("$.info.processMonitor.processList");`

Comment: I will talk to the original developer who added the feature and see about breaking the request into includes/excludes sections since what he has done doesnt allow us to "include everything but..." type expressions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you are actually looking for a JSON transformation. JOLT is a common library to do just that. A solution can look like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.Chainr;
import com.bazaarvoice.jolt.JsonUtils;
 
public class MyJsonTransformer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Object> specs = JsonUtils.classpathToList("/spec.json");
        Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(specs);
 
        Object inputJSON = JsonUtils.classpathToObject("/input.json");
        Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(inputJSON);
        System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyJsonString(transformedOutput));
    }
}
```

And a jolt remover spec file like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "info": {
        "processMonitor": {
          "processList": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

You can try JOLT online with your input and the spec above [here](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/). Pretty neat.
The JSON and spec can be defined inline as well. I have not tested this end to end.

Comment: The coworker that wrote the original code modified it to work appropriately.